# Why does a parallel fadeOut() stop slideup() from working?

Tags: jquery, css, fadeout, slideup

I put together this simple demo to find out why the `slideUp` did not work when items were clicked, and noticed if I remove the `fadeOut` it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/sx8c7uaf/

Simple HTML:

```
<div class="WaffleMaker">
    <div class="Waffle">I am a waffle (toaster notification 1)</div>
    <div class="Waffle">I am a waffle (toaster notification 2)</div>
    <div class="Waffle">I am a waffle (toaster notification 3)</div>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
.WaffleMaker {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.Waffle {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #12a6db;
}
```

Test code:

```
$('.Waffle').click(function () {
    var $waffle = $(this);
    $waffle.fadeOut().slideUp("slow", function () {
        $waffle.remove();
    });
});
```

Why does the presence of `fadeOut` stop the `slideUp` from working?

If you change the fiddle to this it is fine:

```
    $waffle.slideUp("slow", function () {
```

Comment: is it because jquery complete the `fadeOut()` before the next action because what you did was queuing up the actions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the functions gets queued, you can use `.animate` and set queue to false

```
$waffle.slideUp("slow", function () {
    $waffle.remove();
}).animate({opacity:0},{queue:false});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sx8c7uaf/2/)

Comment: As they had different effects, it did not occur to me they were queued! do'h!

Comment: But to answer more completly the reason regarding no slideup animation, it should be said as referred to DOC: `The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.`

Comment: @A. Wolff: Thanks for that info. You have completed the puzzle now and my Toaster Waffles are cooking again :)

Answer (score 2):

The functions are by default a-sync and run when the other is finished. When you combining animations I suggest you use `animate()`.

**Animate example**

Example 1.

```
$('.Waffle').click(function () {
    var $waffle = $(this);
    $($waffle).animate({ height: 0, opacity: 0 }, 'slow');

});
```

When you dont want to work with animate you can shutoff the queue.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sx8c7uaf/3/

**Disable Queue example**

Example 2

```
$('.Waffle').click(function () {
    var $waffle = $(this);
    $waffle.fadeOut({queue: false}).slideUp("slow", function () {
        $waffle.remove();
    });
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sx8c7uaf/4/

Comment: +1: I have gone with parallel animate values, as per your first example, as the *more readable* option but I must give first answer to Anton as both solutions work well. Many thanks